# NSXML parsing error when used with NSData

Tags: iphone, ios, xml, nsurlconnection, nsxmlparser

I have a simple XML file containing a subset list of products. When I load the file from the iOS App bundle and send it through the parser with: `initWithNSURL`, with an `NSURL` pointing to the local file it parses correctly.

However if I download the same file via an `NSURLConnection` and pass it to the parser with `initWithData`, the parsing fails. I can confirm the data is being downloaded correctly because if I perform `NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[downloadedData bytes]];` the outputted string is correct. 
I have a guy feeling it's sometime to do with encoding somewhere along the line, any thoughts?

Comment: NSString* xmlData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
this is what I do , and it's working

Comment: How are you passing that to the parser after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My friend do the parser job,
    NSString* xmlData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

xmlData should look like 
    
         abc  
    
and my friend just analyze the string,and it's work

and I used libxml2 to parse xml with

```
xmlTextReaderPtr reader = xmlReaderForMemory([data bytes], [data length], NULL, NULL,             (XML_PARSE_NOBLANKS | XML_PARSE_NOCDATA | XML_PARSE_NOERROR | XML_PARSE_NOWARNING));

if (reader != NULL) {
    ret = xmlTextReaderRead(reader);
    while (ret == 1) {
        const xmlChar *name, *value;

        name = xmlTextReaderConstName(reader);
        if (name == NULL)
        name = BAD_CAST "--";
        NSString *Name = [NSString stringWithCString:(const char*)name encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

        value = xmlTextReaderConstValue(reader);
        if (value == NULL)
            value = BAD_CAST "\n";
        NSString *Value = [NSString stringWithCString:(const char*)value encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog("%d %d %@ %d %@", 
        xmlTextReaderDepth(reader),
        xmlTextReaderNodeType(reader),
        Name,
        xmlTextReaderIsEmptyElement(reader),
        Value);



        ret = xmlTextReaderRead(reader);
    }
    xmlFreeTextReader(reader);
  }
```

and result is correct too